# VMware failing to start network interfaces (vagrant)

Tags: networking, vmware, vagrant

On some routers, `vagrant up` fails with the following error (or similar, the vmnet* number might change):

```
Vagrant failed to start the VMware network interfaces! The output
of the failed command, if any, is below. The usual cause for this
is invalid configuration of the VMware network components. If
the problem persists, please contact support.

Subnet on vmnet2 is no longer available for usage, please run the network editor to reconfigure different subnet
Failed to start some/all services
```

This is currently happening on my home router, to which I have admin access - is there anything I can do to make this work?

Here is my Vagrantfile, some sensitive data redacted.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = 'dev-vm'
  config.vm.box = 'dev-vm'
  config.vm.box_url = 'redacted'
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
  # VMware Workstation on Windows and Linux
  config.vm.provider :vmware_workstation do |v|
    v.gui = true
    v.vmx['memsize'] = 1024 * 10
    v.vmx['numvcpus'] = 4
  end
```